# What do you call a team of magnificent people?

Tags: single-word-requests

Can you suggest/provide a word for a team of magnificent (intelligent or the likes) people?

I'm thinking of words that are not cliche like geniuses..

Comment: If there are seven of them, you had better call them the [Magnificent Seven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magnificent_Seven). If there are five, [Fab Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fab_Five) (also works for [four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles)).

Comment: The Crystal Gems?

Comment: In (fictional?) sports, the term **Dream Team** is often used.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If by **magnificent** you mean hardcore, kick-ass group of folks, **A-Team** is the term you might be looking for. There is a movie titled that way. :)

Comment: It actually comes from a TV show, if you want to be accurate. The movie is just based on the show. And if you want to avoid cliches, you probably want to stay away from this one - calling a quality team "the A-Team" is about as cliche as you can get.

Comment: Thank you. I was unaware of the TV show until I read your comment.

Comment: @gelolopez: I'm sorry :(

Comment: @talrnu "A-team" as a phrase, I'm sure predates the TV show. They use it in sports, for example, to designate that a school has teams of varying degree in skill. I'm not sure, but I think some militaries refer to their *assault* squads as "a-teams" sometimes, which is more akin to the use in the show and the movie.

Comment: i don't think this works unless you *also* have at least one other team full of not-quite-so-smart people. you can't have an A-team without a B-team, in other words.

Comment: I pity the fool that thinks there's a better term for a team of magnificent people.

Answer (score 20):

Generic: **Dream Team**

Intelligent: **Brain Trust**, or **Think Tank**

Comment: Dream Team is nice because it not only describes the team's excellence as a single unit, but also suggests each individual member is among the best at what they do (the term describes a team made up of a sport's best players, a team which often only exists in fans' dreams). However, it's also a fairly standard cliche, so it might not fit the asker's particular demands.

Answer (score 14):

An efficient, quality team of professionals, especially specialists in their field, is often called a *crack team*.

> *crack* adj. (attributive): Very good, especially at a specified activity or in a specified role. [*OED*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/crack)

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion. "Crack team" emphasises their elite nature while limiting to a team rather than a whole class.

Comment: @Silverfish So does "elite team".

Comment: Consider also "crack squad".

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is ***elite***; unfortunately, it doesn't imply a *team* so much as a *class*.

If "A-team", "crack team", "dream team", etc are valid, then "elite team" is also valid.

Comment: Only the noun form, e.g. the uncountable "the elite", refers specifically to the class. The adjective, "an elite [noun]", literally means "the best" and could only refer to the class with the help of context. Therefore this answer is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically in music, or by analogy to it, you might consider **supergroup**. [From Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergroup_(music)),

> A supergroup is a music group whose members are already successful as solo artists or as part of other groups or well known in other musical professions. Usually used in the context of rock and pop music, the term has been applied to other musical genres such as The Three Tenors in opera.

Comment: Just don't use it to describe a team of mathematicians.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have seen INTELLIGENTSIA come up before in this stackexchange but I am not sure if that is exactly what you want.

I have heard terms such as "boffins" and "eggheads" used while living in London which roughly mean a group of experts.

Comment: egghead seems to be a negative word.

Comment: Intelligentsia refers to the collective intellectuals on a society. It is far.more larger than a group would imply. Think of it as the ruling thinking class.

Comment: @Yaje: It was coined as a pejorative by the Nazis, but it's become ambiguous, like *nerd*.

Answer (score 0):

For a team of magnificent people? I'd use the word **Professionals**. It basically implies that the persons in question are above the norm.